# How can I use linq to properly fill this string array?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

Trying to use `linq` to fill a string array but my debug line only is working in my website for `'debug'` and not `'debug1'`.

It's hard for me to see what's wrong with my array but I know my directory is correct.

```
string class_dir = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["class_dir"];

string[] file_list = Directory.GetFiles(class_dir).Where(i => dependencies.Contains(i.ToLower())).ToArray<string>(); 

input2.Value = "debug";

foreach (string filename in file_list)
        {
            input2.Value = "debug1";
        }
```

Comment: Did you debug the code and check what values you are getting in `file_list` ?

Comment: I can't debug the traditional way for certain reasons but I can say file_list[0] or file_list[1] throws the error System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.

Comment: Sounds like you have an issue with your Where() logic then

Comment: @MarkMcGown have you checked `dependencies` have elements, in `class_dir` you have files which satisfy `dependencies.Contains()`, and all items in `dependencies` are in lower cases or not?

Comment: @MarkMcGown if you cannot debug, log detailed information (whether on console or in file) about things i mentioned on above comment

Comment: @MarkMcGown If 0 is out of range, the array has no elements in it. Try without the Where to see what you’ve got without it. If nothing, that’s your problem. If something, your Where lambda is broken. What’s really in `dependencies`? Don’t tell me what you guess/hope/assume is in it — you know by now that your assumptions about this code are unreliable. Print it out. Confirm it.